# Como puedo generar un select jquery con datos php

Tags: jquery

Tengo una base de datos de platos con los siguientes datos

```
-----------------------------------
|  id_plato |   nombre     | precio |
-----------------------------------
|    123    |   parrillada | 50     |
|    124    |   chorizo    | 10     |
-----------------------------------
```

y bueno mediante una consulta sql yo puedo volverlo a texto plato dentro de javascript:

```
var plato = array();
plato[123] = array("nombre" => "parrillada","precio"=>"50");
plato[124] = array("nombre" => "choriso","precio"=>"10");
```

lo que quiero que me ayuden es en lo siguiente porfavor:

1. esta bien esta forma de trabajar con array javascript ? de no ser asi cual seria le mejor manera?
2. como puedo hacer una funcion que al llamarla me retorne algo asi:

```
// funcion
function getOption(var_index){...}
// llamada 
getOption("123"); // pongo "123" porque quiero que ese sea el option selected pero si no le pongo nada me muestre las option sin selected
//return 
<option value="123" selected>parrillada</option>
<option value="124">chorizo</option>
```

3. una funcion que al mandarle el id me retorne el precio

```
function getPrecio(item){...}
// llamada 
getPrecio("123");
//return 
50 // precio del item 123
```

Notas:

- la idea es que estas funciones esten basadas en un solo array (plato[])
- deseo escribirlo en texto plano para no tener que hacer un php solo para que me devuelva los la consulta
- la funcion `getPrecio();` la necesito para cuando un cliente cambie el valor de un select jquery me detecte su id y me muestre el precio
- la funcion `getOption();` es para que cuando un cliente de click en el boton agregar pedido me cree un select con todos los option de los platos

[image: los select de platos se cargaran varias veces el mismo, y cuando cree una nueva fila volvere a generar un select con los platos]

Comment: No entiendo mucho por qué quieres llevar tu lógica al cliente. Eso no serviría en un contexto real, llegará el momento en que habrá que implementar la Caja por ejemplo, donde se irán agregando los platos que cada cliente vaya pidiendo, si no trabajas la lógica en el servidor nada de lo que habrás hecho te servirá, porque un cliente no puede conectarse con otro cliente para esto, tienes que centralizar todo en el servidor y puedes usar Ajax para que **cada cliente** pida los platos que quiera al servidor.

Comment: el que esta confundido soy yo, no entendi tu comentario

Comment: Que `getOption()` y `getPrecio()` no tienen sentido, si lo piensas bien. En resumen: puedes cargar la información de los platos desde el servidor vía Ajax (podrías usar los atributos `data-` para guardar en cada `option` otros valores como precio), puedes mostrar cada plato con su precio al lado (es así como se muestran en los menús de cualquier sitio), puedes recoger los platos que el usuario vaya pidiendo en un objeto e ir contabilizando el sub-total según los precios mediante código JS y cuando haya seleccionado todo mandar la orden al servidor.

Comment: La lógica que tienes que implementar en Javascript es controlar el pedido, por ejemplo, la cantidad de platos que el cliente seleccione, ir sumando e informando al cliente qué precio va teniendo su pedido, etc. No preocuparte por mostrar información que ya tienes como es el precio. Además un `select` quizá no sea lo mejor desde el punto de vista de UX. En un menú de restaurante tú ves todo de golpe o por grupos (entrantes, platos principales, postres, bebidas) pero no tienes que pasar página para ver cada plato. Deberías pensar en una forma más simple para el usuario.

Comment: amigo mira edite mi pregunta y subi una foto para que masomenos me entiendas;
yo necesito cargar una sola vez mis platos porque los mismos select se repetiran en cada tr de la tabla, y cuando le de en añadir fila me creara un tr con un select basado en los platos. mira la imagen porfavor.
ahora bien, no puse que este formulario no es para el cliente si no para el mozo que se encargara de hacer el pedido

Comment: Pienso que un `select` para esto es incómodo desde el punto de vista de la experiencia del usuario (UX). Piensa en la idea de un menú de restaurante, tú tienes una lista de platos y al lado el precio, de golpe ves todos los platos que hay, en `select` vez un solo plato, por lo que para fines de menú es poco práctico (una opción interesante podría ser `checkbox`). Aparte de eso, no entiendo lo que dices sobre el precio, pues en la imagen ya muestras el precio al lado.

Comment: amigo te comento que esto es para el mozo, no para el cliente

Comment: - ese precio es cambiable, es decir cuando el mozo cambie de plato mediante el select aparecera el precio del nuevo plato. por eso quiero la funcion getPrecio(); para cuando el mozo cambie mediante el select el producto este detecte el precio del id del option seleccionado
- es un formulario para el mozo, no para el cliente; al cliente se le brindara un menu fisico y el mozo generara el pedido de manera digital

Comment: No importa. El camarero es un "cliente" (un usuario) del programa que estás creando y tienes que diseñar el programa de la forma más amigable y fácil posible (eso es lo que se conoce como UX y afecta el rendimiento y la productividad). En tu diseño el camarero va a perder más tiempo manejando el programa y el servicio por ese motivo irá más lento. No sé si me explico. Si el camarero tiene todo en pantalla y va chequeando simplemente es más fácil que ir moviéndose entre `option`  de varios `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion, la publico para los que deseen integrarla o tambien para que los desarrolladores mas avanzados puedan corregirlo o perfecionarlo.
**Texto plano generado con consulta php/mysql:**

```
var platos = [
{"id":"123","nombre":"Parrilla de Carne","precio":"10"},
{"id":"124","nombre":"Parrilla de Cerdo","precio":"11"}
];
```

**recorrer los datos, generar los option y almacenarlos en variable optionss:**

```
optionss ="";
for (var i = 0; i < platos.length; i++) {
optionss += "<option value='"+platos[i]["id"]+"'>" +  platos[i]["nombre"] + "</option>\n";
}
console.log(optionss);
```

**Obtener el precio/nombre/id segun un ID:**

```
var getInfo = $.grep(platos, function(v) {
    return v.id === "123"; // este valor 123 cambia por el que desees
});


console.log(getInfo[0].precio);
```

*no lo meti en una funcion por falta de tiempo pero los que saben de javascript lo podran hacer....*

Espero les sirva